# Como convertir datetime a string en C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, sql

Estoy intentando convertir el valor datetime de un dateTimePicker a string, para luego pasarla como valor en un query sql, sin embargo me genera el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En SQL también tienes formato de fecha para almacenar los datos. Además, si pasas esas variables como fecha, te servirán si luego necesitas hacer cálculos o búsquedas sobre dichas fechas

Comment: ¿[`ToString`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: como menciona @el.trasgu es recomendable que en la base de datos los campos sean tambien de tipo fecha, asi no tendras problemas mas adelante y facilita las consultas y reportes.

Comment: Manten las fechas como fechas. No tiene sentido cambiarlas a cadenas para luego guardarlas de nuevo como fechas.

Answer (score 3):

Si deseas solamente la fecha:

```
var d = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

//Resultado: 31/08/2021
```

Si deseas fecha y hora:

```
var d2 = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");

//Resultado: 31/08/2021 08:41
```

Comment: eso mismo aplicaria para las otras 2? ya que tengo 3  variables de fecha en la orden

Comment: así mismo estimado @KevinCastillo

Comment: muchas graciass

Comment: Hola, ayúdanos agregando el código como texto en lugar de imágenes, saludos.

Comment: Listo, edité la respuesta y se quito la imagen. thank..